# How to animate a Bitmap in a canvas (Android)

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, translate-animation

I'm using a class that uses onDraw(Canvas canvas) method to draw one or more Bitmap in different positions.If i want animate one of these Bitmaps after an event ( onTouchEvent ),and if I know the position of all Bitmaps,how can I translate the selected Bitmap to another position?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the position of drawn bitmap. You have to redraw it by using invalidate() method after changing position of bitmaps.

Comment: Where do I put invalidate() in my class? in OnTouchEvent? How do I use it? and finally,can i create a traslateAnimation using Bitmaps in a canvas?

Comment: isn't possible to make an animation with more than one bitmaps in a canvas object?must I use layouts and ImageViews?